# Calling one app from another app with URL passed as argument in Android

Tags: android, url, android-intent

I want to call b.apk from a.apk and b.apk reads a URL from a file and opens it in browser. I am able to do that with the help of 'intent'.
Below is the code for the same:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent1.setClassName("own.example.weburl", "own.example.weburl.NewWebViewActivity");
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT );
startActivity(intent1);
```

Now I want to do the same thing , but I want to pass the URL to b.apk to open it instead of b.apk reading it from the file. So b.apk should just open the URL it received as argument. I went through Android Developer website to look for a way to do this, but couldn't find any.
How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("YOUR URL HERE"));
startActivity(i);
```

This should work

Comment: thanks a lot for ur reply!
it is working for me, but in a different way as it is directly opening the URL instead of passing it to b.apk and then opening it through b.apk.